# WKWebView in background, several strange assertion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to find out userAgent of current browser in iOS.

So in default project created by Xcode  I added:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WKWebView.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        WKWebView *obj = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [obj evaluateJavaScript: @"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript = %@ : %@", result, error);
            NSLog(@"To make sure that webview alive: %@", obj);
        }];
    });
}


@end
```

it prints what I expect:

> evaluateJavaScript = Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 14_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 : (null)

but after that it prints:

> test4[1930:101220] usage: <WKWebView: 0x7f958f817800; frame = (0 0; 0
> 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000236ed00>>
>
> test4[1930:101220] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error
> Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or
> required target entitlement is missing"
> UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute|
> domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background"
> sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not
> running or required target entitlement is missing}>
>
> test4[1930:101220] [ProcessSuspension] 0x102dfed00 - ProcessAssertion:
> Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background
> Assertion' for process with PID 1933, error: Error
> Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or
> required target entitlement is missing"
> UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute|
> domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background"
> sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not
> running or required target entitlement is missing}

This doesn't look good. Is something wrong with my code,
is it possible to avoid these assertions and still get userAgent string?

Comment: just read the error msg `"Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing"` which is also correct failure because you can apply a different userAgent string with your own implementation you just did. And you assert javascript before the view did load complete.

Comment: @OlSen how did you conclude all that simply by looking at `"Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing"`? For me this isn't clear at all.

Comment: Hm how did you exactly solve this problem?
I have a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571345/ios-iphone-11-flashing-black-and-white-while-browsler-is-constantly-reloading-r

Comment: @MarcelSchürmann Reference to `webView` should keep alive until `completionHandler` and destroyed in that handler, so in `completionHandler`  I call `dispatch_async` and then in main queue I destroy `webView`.