# iOS iPhone 11 flashing black and white while browsler is constantly reloading: RBS Background assertion ConnectionTerminationWatchdog

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, cordova, wkwebview

I get a black & white flashing browser, which is constantly reloading after this error:

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1063b4740 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process because PID is invalid
[Process] 0x104028a18 - [pageProxyID=11, webPageID=12, PID=3734] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 3734), reason 3
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
```

The issue occurs only with iPhone 11 PRO and iPhone 11 Mini (real devices) and a cordova app on iOS 14.3, 14.4 and 14.5.
On emulator it works perfectly and on other real devices as well.

In my case the screen is flashing black and white if I open a dc-Tableview.js table (by adding and removing "diplay:none").

**Related issues:**

- [WKWebView is trying to run on background, although it's closed and should be disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162287/wkwebview-is-trying-to-run-on-background-although-its-closed-and-should-be-dis)
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1103
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-background-issue/206463
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677916?login=true&page=1#674912022
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/issues/55

**System:**

- Cordova 10.0.0
- Cordova-ios 6.2.0
- iPhone 11 PRO / iPhone 11 Mini (it is woring on several other devices f.e. iPhone SE, also working on iPhone 11 PRO emulator)
- iOS 14.5

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: I got the same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: Hi @NguyenTran: Unfortunately not but I think it has to do with the new display technology "OLED Super Retina XDR" - see my comment below in the other answer. It only occurs on iPhone 11 PRO and later versions with this display technology, not iPhone 11.

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue, but only on iOS 14, in 12 and 13 just work perfect...can any one solve this? please let me know. :(

Answer (score 2):

It seems to occure **when the screen is scrolled**:

- manually
- by using functions like: `scrollintoview()`
- with **multiple full-size modals** used with `overflow-y: auto` css in modal div container

*Edit:*
Finally, I could solve my issue by **hiding all inactive modals** in the background by using:

- `display: none`

Removing the modals, removes the error.

Resizing the modals, removes the error (f.e. height to 30%).

When I delete all my `scrollintoview()` occurances I only get the flashing bug when scrolling manually.

Hope this helps. Still I don't know how to solve that entirely.

I opened a ticket at apple support:
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9363100

Comment: Finally, could solve the issue.
I had many modals which were hidden (put to the background by changing position).
Now instead I hide all the modals (`display: none`) and after I display only the active modals (`display: block` or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem:

```
Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing
```

I enabled Background modes -> Background processing under capabilities and since then, I don't see this issue. Hope this works for you as well!

Update: This does not fix my issue, you can try if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
So the error message just disappeared but you still have the flashing problem?
I will test it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I still see error message. My problem - webview reload the last loaded page after this error.

Comment: My webview is also reloading.
I am testing the background modes now. 
But the background mode "background processing" is something else I think (when app is in background and processing some tasks in another thread). Maybe this helps for clarification: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode or https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode-fixed

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while capturing the images in real devices. @MarcelSchürmann did you find any working solution for this.

Comment: Hi @PritamSalunkhe Unfortunately not yet (the background mode "background fetch" did not resolve the issue and "Background processing" is more complex and I think something else... I have no iPhone 11 to make regular tests in depth. I think it could be a problem concerning the cache, performance or rendering. I am loading large javascript libraries (crossfilter, d3, dc-tableview, dc, ion.rangeSlider, papaparse etc.) and a lot of data which is loaded in local cache. Then I am creating a Table (dc-tableview), which generates the crash. Do you have any similar libraries or any hint?

Comment: @MarcelSchürmann In my case, I am using my custom camera plugin wherein after capturing the picture I am adding some text on images. It seems it is related to the memory issue. As I commented out the code for adding text on images then it works fine for me. I have observed this when memory consumption goes around 200 or 240 MB after that I will get this crash.

Comment: @PritamSalunkhe Thanks for the input. In my case Memory consumption is not very hight (only around 20-30 MB). But I have a Table with Images, DIVs and Background gradient - maybe this could be the issue?
I also noticed, that it sometimes does not crash until i start scrolling. Maybe it has something to do with the iPhone 11 touch / general rendering of the images and DIVs.

Comment: @Marcel Can you please check for Memory leaks and fixing those might resolve your issue.

Comment: @PritamSalunkhe: What exactly do you mean with memory leaks? How can I check this?

Comment: @MarcelSchürmann you can check this memory leaks part with the Instrument and Memory Graph tools using XCode.

Comment: I got some news... The bug only occurs on iPhone 11 PRO and higher (not iPhone 11).
It seems to be because of the new display technology called "OLED Super Retina XDR".
Here some issues about the new display technology:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/iphone-12-pro-raised-blacks-display.2263200/page-52
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251997533
https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/03/iphone-x-eye-strain-how-to-stop-oled-flickering-in-just-three-clicks/

Unfortunately I have no solution yet - will make some further tests.

Comment: HI @MarcelSchürmann, no good news so far ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @lmarcelocc, I could reduce the issue:
For me it occurs when I have **multiple modals** (5-30) in my app with **full width and height**.
When I remove the modals, I do not get the flashing error. 
Also when I reduce the size of the modals (reduce height) I have no error.
Hope this helps... Still I don't know what the problem exactly is... Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, remove `autofocus=true` from the HTML page fixed for me,

Inspired by  omnir95's comment on
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121822?page=3

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me in IOS 15.3 , just update your real device as the current xcode "13.2.1" emulators with the version 15.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used logScrolling() and ion-fab (overflow element) on a page where I displayed many rows in a list contains images and text. I logged the scrolling to display/hide the ion-fab. If I deleted the ion-fab from html the app run without any problem. The solution was that I used ion-virtual-scroll (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll) instead of use simple ngFor.